# Replacing/Adding values to HTML written as a PERL string

Tags: javascript, regex, html, perl

So, I have a HTML which is written into a perl string. This html represents a template and I need to add fields on runtime.
For example:

```
  $templateHTML.= '<span   > %{name} </span>
```

I want to replace the %{name} with the required value.
The regex I have tried is:

```
  $htmlTemplate.=~ s/%{name}/akhil;
```

This didn't work, also is there a way I can use JavaScript's replace function, i.e, can I convert the perl string to js string and process it?

On request, the template is invoked and the values to be added are passed as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This solved:

```
   my $find = "%{name}";
   my $replace = "had";
   $find = quotemeta $find; # escape regex metachars if present

   $str =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
```

Source : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=98357

Giving the values directly, didn't work. I am not sure why, will look up and get back.

Comment: Inside regex you can use `\Q..\E`. Actually `$str =~ s/%{name}/$replace/g;`, it will work, in your original question you are concatenating the values while doing the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You're inventing your own templating system. And it seems unlikely that you'll invent something as flexible or powerful as the ones we already have. So I'd recommend you use something like [the Template Toolkit](http://tt2.org/) instead.

But if you want to continue with your plan, you should read the relevant section from [the FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html).

> [**How can I expand variables in text strings?**](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3F)
>
> (contributed by brian d foy)
>
> If you can avoid it, don't, or if you can use a templating system, such as Text::Template or Template Toolkit, do that instead. You might even be able to get the job done with `sprintf` or `printf`:
>
> ```
>    my $string = sprintf 'Say hello to %s and %s', $foo, $bar;
> ```
>
> However, for the one-off simple case where I don't want to pull out a full templating system, I'll use a string that has two Perl scalar variables in it. In this example, I want to expand `$foo` and `$bar` to their variable's values:
>
> ```
>    my $foo = 'Fred';
>    my $bar = 'Barney';
>    $string = 'Say hello to $foo and $bar';
> ```
>
> One way I can do this involves the substitution operator and a double `/e` flag. The first `/e` evaluates `$1` on the replacement side and turns it into `$foo`. The second `/e` starts with $foo and replaces it with its value. `$foo`, then, turns into 'Fred', and that's finally what's left in the string:
>
> ```
>    $string =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg; # 'Say hello to Fred and Barney'
> ```
>
> The `/e` will also silently ignore violations of strict, replacing undefined variable names with the empty string. Since I'm using the `/e` flag (twice even!), I have all of the same security problems I have with eval in its string form. If there's something odd in `$foo`, perhaps something like `@{[ system "rm -rf /" ]}`, then I could get myself in trouble.
>
> To get around the security problem, I could also pull the values from a hash instead of evaluating variable names. Using a single `/e`, I can check the hash to ensure the value exists, and if it doesn't, I can replace the missing value with a marker, in this case ??? to signal that I missed something:
>
> ```
>    my $string = 'This has $foo and $bar';
>    my %Replacements = (
>        foo  => 'Fred',
>        );
>    # $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/$Replacements{$1}/g;
>    $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/
>                exists $Replacements{$1} ? $Replacements{$1} : '???'
>                /eg;
>    print $string;
> ```